# How to generate 2 different random arrays of numbers using a C'tor in c++?

Tags: c++, random, constructor

I am trying to create to different objects from the class 'NumSet'.
NumSet Player1,player2;
It generates 1 array properly - with random numbers.
But the second one is copied just the same.
The array of player one is equal to the array of player2.
How to solve this ? 
Thanks.

```
NumSet::NumSet()
{
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < C_NUM; i++) {//Generate 2 random arrays.
        n_cards[i] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    }
}
```

For example player1 will looks like that: {3,4,5,2,5}
which is good (initialized with random numbers).
The problem I dont know how to solve is that player2 will be exactly the same:
{3,4,5,2,5}

Comment: You should seed the random number generator once, only (call srand once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use old style `rand`, and don't want to call `srand` outside the class, then do some more of *dirtiness*. Have a `static` variable in class, call it `IsRandomSeeded`, and conditionally call `srand`

```
bool NumSet::IsRandomSeeded=false;

NumSet::NumSet()
{
    if(!IsRandomSeeded)
    {
       srand(time(0));
       IsRandomSeeded  = true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < C_NUM; i++) {//Generate 2 random arrays.
        n_cards[i] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working great thank you! Could you elaborate on how the static variable helps?

Answer (score 3):

`rand()` number generator is not *really* random, it produces a pseudo-random sequence based on one given initial seed. With same seed you will produce same sequence again and again.

If you create both objects fast enough (within same second) to get same seed from `time(NULL)` then you will have exactly the same sequence. Solution is to move random number generator initialization outside class constructor (ideally in your `main()` function).

If you do not worry to use *experimental* C++ functions you may also use this:

```
std::experimental::reseed();
for (int i = 0; i < C_NUM; i++) {
    n_cards[i] = std::experimental::randint(1, 10);
}
```

Note that `rand()` is not thread-safe then it may be an issue in your case. If you can't move `srand()` outside constructor (!!!) and you can't use `std::experimental` stuff then you should provide a static function to generate random numbers with a flag to call `srand()` just once. Alternatively do not directly use `time(NULL)` but an incremental number:

```
static unsigned seed = time(NULL);
srand(seed++);
```

Note: `rand()` is not a good random generator and it doesn't produce an uniform distribution, its advantage is to be fast and for *casual* tasks (like this one) it's more than enough...

Comment: can I solve this somehow in the c'tor ? It's one of the mission requirements.

Comment: @IsanRivkin it's ok to populate the array in constructor. You only need to move `srand`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the random libraries provided in C++11 if available. Here is a quick example http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    // Seed with a real random value, if available
    std::random_device r;

    // Choose a random mean between 1 and 6
    std::default_random_engine e1(r());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 6);
    int mean = uniform_dist(e1);
    std::cout << "Randomly-chosen mean: " << mean << '\n';

    // Generate a normal distribution around that mean
    std::seed_seq seed2{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()}; 
    std::mt19937 e2(seed2);
    std::normal_distribution<> normal_dist(mean, 2);

    std::map<int, int> hist;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10000; ++n) {
        ++hist[std::round(normal_dist(e2))];
    }
    std::cout << "Normal distribution around " << mean << ":\n";
    for (auto p : hist) {
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << std::setw(2)
                  << p.first << ' ' << std::string(p.second/200, '*') << '\n';
    }
}
```